# Edit data in tecplot

Tags: paraview

The results I get in tecplot through the generated .vtk files are too small (eg magnitude of ^-18) this is because I run an analysis through a scaled down model.

I would like to give the results in a exagerated form so that deflection and stresses are very visible. So I need to multiply my results with a factor.

Can I do this in the tecplot interface or should I find a way to write the .vtk files with a magnification factor.

A method to do either would be much appreciated.

PS - I have used the calculator in paraview so is there something similar in tecplot ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new variable using the [tecplot calculator](http://www.tecplot.com/blog/2013/09/04/tecplot-tip-calculating-a-new-variable/). It is in :

Data > Alter > Specify Equations

In this menu :

1. select the zone you want to alter (in case of doubt, select all the zones)
2. create a new variable *NEW_VAR* that will be the original variable *VAR* multiplied by a factor (eg. 100) :

   {NEW_VAR} = {VAR}*100
3. use the "Compute" button

NB :

- Variables names must be put between braces
- You can find the names of the variables with the "Data Set Info..." button, in the top right corner of the "Specify Equations" menu.